# SqlDataAdapter with Join statement

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, n-tier-architecture

I have a storedProcedure with joining four table . I want to bind the result from different table in a gridview control.

here is my data access layer code

```
aCommand = new SqlCommand("spViewPatientHistory", aConnection);
aCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
aCommand.Parameters.Add("@PatientId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = patientId;
aCommand.Parameters.Add("@FirstName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = firstName;
aCommand.Parameters.Add("@LastName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = lastName;
aDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(aCommand);
aDataAdapter.Fill(aDataSet);
aConnection.Close();
```

and this is my business logic  code

```
aHistoryPatientDataTable = aDataAccess.GetSearchPatientHistory(patientId,firstName,lastName);
```

In business logic it show a error

Cannot convert dataset to dataTable . How to solve it ?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8983277/how-to-convert-dataset-to-datatable

Answer (score 0):

Little bit ambiguous question due to lake of code 
but i think you are returning dataset and assigning dataset to dataTable

use your code like that

```
aHistoryPatientDataTable = aDataAccess.GetSearchPatientHistory(patientId,firstName,lastName).GetDataSet().Tables[0];
```

Hope this will help